# Postgresql の gin とはどのような特徴をもつインデックス形式ですか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

`Rails`で`Postgresql`を使用しておりカラムに配列をもたせようとしたところRailsガイドの解説ではインデックスの方式に`gin`という物が使われていました。

```
create_table :books do |t|
  t.string 'title'
  t.string 'tags', array: true
  t.integer 'ratings', array: true
end
add_index :books, :tags, using: 'gin'
add_index :books, :ratings, using: 'gin'
```

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array

検索してみてもそういうインデックス形式があるとわかるだけで具体的にどのような特徴を持つアルゴリズムかわかりませんでした。

カラムに配列を使う時は必ず`gin`を指定すべきなのでしょうか？
また`gin`がどのような条件で最適の選択肢になるかが知りたいです。

Comment: [gin は転置索引のこと](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/gin-intro.html)だと思うので、[こちら](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BB%A2%E7%BD%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9)が参考になるかもしれません。(既にご存知でしたらすみません。)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。一通り読んでみたのですが本来文章を単語に分割して転置したインデックスを構築するのが転置索引ということは、配列に対して転置索引行うとは『それぞれの要素で分解してから転置をしてインデックスを作成してる』ということでしょうか？